# Android - Prepare Media Recorder Failed

Tags: android, camera, android-mediarecorder

Im Trying to do something simple, record audio and video without preview.

Here is my code:

```
MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

// Configure the input sources
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

// Set the output format
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);

// Specify the audio and video encoding        
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);

    //Specify the outputfile
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/Video/myoutputfile.mp4");

mediaRecorder.start();

In the AndroidManisfest.xml:
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
```

This stops the application when it launches.

Anyone has any ideia?

Comment: Don't forget <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Typo: 'user-permission' should be 'uses-permission'. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to call this before you start the record;

```
mediaRecorder.prepare();
```

Also, keep in mind you are missing a few necessary "features" you *must* set before calling prepare.
Here seems to be a few methods you are missing;

```
setPreviewDisplay();
setMaxDuration((int) #); 
setOnInfoListener();
setVideoSize(#, #); 
setVideoFrameRate(15);
```

Comment: I tried again, and got the same error, the app crashes before start!

Comment: Is there something about the fact that I'm testing this in a Galaxy Nexus? Android 4.1.1. I read that this code doesn't work in android 2.3 or higher.

Comment: Can you edit your stack trace? I got it to work on my Galaxy Nexus with some weird settings, but yes I remember EXACTLY my galaxy nexus crashing A LOT with the class MediaRecorder!! (Big surprise, because its supposed to be a google backed phone using google api's? haha)

Using my "special" settings never work out for me because obviously it would only work on my nexus then, and other phones would have problems :(

Comment: So, this still didn't worked on nexus, but in older devices, its great, using the methods I forgot. For galaxy nexus, try this: http://android-er.blogspot.com.br/2011/10/simple-exercise-of-video-capture-using.html worked for me (: